# How to prevent re-render with state update in REACT hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

(I hope you understand what I want to say although I am not good at English.)

Hello.
I migrate code which is written class component to function component.
But I have faced several problems like this:

1. I found no way for migrating shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle. I know React.memo can handle it like shouldComponentUpdate. But this way only can be applied on props update. I need this process on state update.
2. When you want to change a few state at once, what do you do for it? How can I migrate this code to function component?

   class sample: `this.setState({aaa: 'a', bbb: 'b', ccc: 1});`

   => Do you just call all method?

   migration example: `setAaa(); setBbb(); setCcc();`
3. I don't know how to add callback function with useState.

   class sample: `this.setState({state: value}, ()=> {callback function});`

   migration exmple: (not solved)

Here is sample code that is similar to my code that should be migrated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-firefly-sq1dm9?file=/src/App.js

I can't attach real code because of security, so I just tried to put all problem that I should solve.

Thank you :)

Comment: Please ask one question per question, and put all relevant code into the question as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: There is no direct 1-to-1 relation between the old class-based mechanisms and the new function-based mechanisms. You will need to understand the new way of _thinking_ in a function way, some of the old mechanisms simply are obsolete.
1. Why do you need to prevent re-renders? when state changes, you need to re-render. if you have values that should not trigger re-renders store them in `useRef`.
2. Yes you can just call multiple state setters in a row.
3. There are no callbacks after state updated. What exactly do you want to do after it? maybe a `useEffect` will do.

Comment: @ggorlen Oh I see. I will do that from next time !

Comment: @Martin thank you for your comment. :)
1. I can't replace it to useRef because sometimes it should re-render.
2. Okay. I will do like that.
3. Although useEffect is much useful hook in react, I think it can't be the answer.
I want to call callback method only on sometimes not always after state update.
If I put a state 'aaa' on array of useEffect, then callback method in useEffect will be executed every time that 'aaa' updated.

Comment: @loveloper.dev You can setup a `useEffect` with a dependency to `aaa` and in the effect function you can check if `aaa` meets a condition to decide if you call a nested callback or instead do nothing.

Comment: @Martin hello, thank you for giving me comments. But if you don't mind, I want you to read this question for me.
I attached simple sample code that contains what I really want to do.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72518413/could-i-use-callback-function-after-executing-usestate-in-specific-case-react

Answer (score 1):

1. 

```
useEffect(() => {
// do stuff here

}, [someState]) // will be triggered only when someState changes

useEffect(() => {
// do stuff here

}, []) // will be triggered once on first render

useEffect(() => {
// do stuff here

}) // will be triggered on each render

useEffect(() => {
// do stuff here
const timer = setTimeout(() => console.log('hi'), 5000)
return () => clearTimeout(timer); // you can unsubscribe of any 
// listeners here
}, []) // will be triggered once on first render
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I think I can't take this way because setTimeOut is not appropriate in my case.

Comment: it was just an example to show how to use useEffect()