# Could I use callback function after executing React.useState in specific cases?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

Hello :) I recently do migrating task react class component to function component.
And I am given only 2days to figure out whether it can be migrated perfectly or not.
It is actually first experience with function component and hook for me, so I faced some problem with this work.

This is one of difficulties: migrating a callback function which is called after executing useState only in specific cases.

I already know there is useEffect for altering several tasks such as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and callback function.

But I think I can't fire useEffect at the exact time I want.

Here is my sample code.

I know there is correct way to print 'changed' without callback method.
But I made this sample only for showing the location where I want to put callback function.

```
  class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      aaa: 200,
      bbb: 200,
      ccc: "black"
    };
  }

  handleClick = (target, e) => {
    if (target === "div") {
      this.setState({ aaa: 300, bbb: 300, ccc: "yellow" }, () => {
        // It is what I want to do: Calling callback function in specific case.
        // I don't want to change innerText whenever states are changed.
        document.getElementById("box").innerText = "changed!";
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ aaa: 300, bbb: 300, ccc: "pink" });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { aaa, bbb, ccc } = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <div
          id="box"
          onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "div")}
          style={{
            display: "inline-block",
            marginBottom: "30px",
            width: aaa,
            height: bbb,
            backgroundColor: ccc
          }}
        >
          click it!
        </div>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "button")}>
          click it!
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm confused what you mean abut `useState` here? You have a class-based component so you can't use React Hooks in it.

Comment: Also to pass an argument in your `onClick` you need to write it like this instead: `onClick={() => this.handleClick("div")}`. The way you wrote it, it's not a function, but the return value of `this.handleClick`, which is nothing/`undefined`.

Comment: @Slbox I do migrate class-based component to function-based component. So I want to know how can I code with function-based component that has same functions with the sample class-based component. 

And I modified code. I will happy if you check it again.